# Обработка адреса сайта

Tags: php, html

Добрый вечер. Есть такое условие:

```
 Проверка должна срабатывать при любом формате ввода адреса:

site.com

www.site.com

http://site.com

https://site.com
```

Подскажите, как реализовать корректную обработку адреса в поле, чтобы скрипт работал корректно? Предполагаю, что с помощью паттернов?

Comment: RFC3986: `^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?`

Comment: Ого. Подскажите ещё как его использовать? Никогда не пользовался паттернами

Comment: А пресловутая "проверка" должна также учитывать, что `site.com` и `www.site.com` могут быть совсем разными страницами?

Comment: Не знаю. Это тестовое задание и с этим пунктом у меня пока никаких идей. Нужно обязательно уточнить, спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, вам подойдёт html5 input[type=url]

```
<input type="url" />
```

RFC3986 определяет следующий паттерн для URI: `^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?`

Можно уточнить поле ввода своим паттерном (вы же не хотите всякие `ftp://...`?)

Например:

```
<input type="url" pattern="https?://.+"/>
```

Или что-то посложнее:

```
<input type="url" pattern="^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:[^\/\.]+\.)+[^\/\.]+"/>
```

Тест регулярки:

```js
const reg = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:[^\/\.]+\.)+[^\/\.]+/;

const samples = [
  'http://www.example.com',
  'https://example.com',
  'www.example.com',
  'example.com',
];

console.log(samples.map(sample => reg.test(sample)));

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(document.querySelector('input').validity.valid)
});
```

```html
<input type="url" pattern="^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:[^\/\.]+\.)+[^\/\.]+"/> <!-- Регулярка изменена, иначе -->
<button>Check</button>
```

---

*Использован [ответ с enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13821385/2110496)*

Comment: Я что-то не могу понять теперь какой вид должна иметь строка)

Comment: Когда я ввожу в одном из 4-х форматов, то мне выдаёт, чтобы я ввёл данные в указанном формате

Comment: Перепроверьте регулярку, у меня была ошибка в конце. Нужно было сразу проверить.

Comment: Работает. Спасибо большое. Вы эти регулярки наизусть помните или на каком-то сайте смотрите?

Comment: Нет, на глаз составляю. Это как на другом языке говорить, нужно понять и проблем не будет.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое

Comment: @vp_arth на сервере тоже надо бы проверку сделать... Исходный код в браузере без труда можно подделать.

Comment: Изменил регулярку, чтобы слеши не совпадали в части домена, иначе sftp://x.y.z тоже пройдёт

Comment: @Эдуард, я там понимаю, задача носит академический характер. На сервере лучше всего проверять HEAD запросом по этому адресу.

Comment: Это тестовое задание мне прислали для приёма на работу

Comment: Тогда Вам необходимо, как минимум, понять, как и почему это работает. Во-первых, могут спросить, во-вторых, придётся с этим работать =)

Comment: Я знаю для чего регулярные выражения. Но вот читать, а тем более составлять их я не умею)